# How to add an image/button to a UITextView? With auto line break?

Tags: iphone, image, button, uitextview, break

I want to add an image/button to my UITextView and the text should automatically make a line break that the image/button fits.

Second question. I want to make a button called "move image/button" and then the user can move the image/button through the UITextView and the text should `adjust`.

PS: like in "Pages" for mac or "Word" for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is decidedly non-trivial. For starters, you can't simply embed a UIImage inside a UITextView and even if you could text wouldn't magically flow around it. What you'll need to do is create your own object based on a UITextView that substantially extends its capabilities to provide such editing tools.

For a heads-up as to what you're getting into you might want to take a look at the [example Text Editor source code](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor/) from the Omni Group.

Comment: ok thank you very much for you help. Mayby it's really to much for me. Mayby I can find an other solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attributedText` property of `UITextView` with an `NSAttributedString` with `NSTextAttachment` with image. Note that the `UITextView` must be `Selectable` (in Storyboard).

Swift demonstration:

```
let attributedImage = NSAttributedString(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "myImage"))
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello ")
attributedText.append(attributedImage)
textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

Where the `attributedImage` is built from those convenience initializers:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    convenience init(with image: UIImage) {
        self.init(attachment: NSTextAttachment(with: image))
    }
}
extension NSTextAttachment {
    convenience init(with image: UIImage) {
        self.init()
        self.image = image
        // adjust origin if needed
        self.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)
    }
}
```

This solution works for: iOS 7.0, macOS 10.11, tvOS 9.0, *.